# python web scraping data to csv

Tags: python, csv

I was trying to use python web scraping then output a csv file but the print format is not matching csv format.

output[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7MiC.png)

how to print this expecting results?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zcwo0.png)

Thanks

Below is my script

```
import urllib.request as req
import bs4
import csv
import pandas as pd
import re
from datetime import date, timedelta

def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    for n in range(int((end_date - start_date).days)):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)

start_date = date(2021, 12, 10)
end_date = date(2021, 12, 15)
url="https://hkgoldprice.com/history/"

with open('gprice.csv','w',newline="") as f1:
    for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
        udate = single_date.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
        urld = url + single_date.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
        writer=csv.writer(f1,delimiter = '\t',lineterminator='\n',)
        writer.writerows(udate)

        print(udate)
        with req.urlopen(urld) as response:
            data=response.read().decode("utf-8")
            root=bs4.BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
            prices=root.find_all("div",class_="gp")
            gshops=root.find_all("div",class_="gshop")
            gpdate=root.find_all("div",class_="gp_date")
            for price in prices:
                print(price.text)
                row = price
                writer.writerows(row)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is you use "writerows", which will lead csv write become several rows as it can. So when your text is "2021/12/23", the converter will become ['2', '0', '2', '1', '/', '1', '2', '/', '2', '3'], and write each row with one char. Same problem as the price. So we use "writerow" and save row data as a list to prevent csv convert our data to multiple rows.

The second is use `.text` in BeautifulSoup will record all the text including whitespaces and lead csv behavior unpredictable. So I will delete all whitespace and `#` first to prevent this situation.

Here is the modified code

```
with open('gprice.csv','w',newline="") as f1:
    for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
        udate = single_date.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
        urld = url + single_date.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
        #we will append row by row, so we just use default setting on csv write
        writer=csv.writer(f1)
        #define empty row list
        row_list = []
        #append datetime
        row_list.append(udate)
    
        with req.urlopen(urld) as response:
            data=response.read().decode("utf-8")
            root=bs4.BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
            prices=root.find_all("div",class_="gp")
            gshops=root.find_all("div",class_="gshop")
            gpdate=root.find_all("div",class_="gp_date")
            for price in prices:
                #get inner text and delete '#'
                row = price.text.replace('#', '')
                #delete all whitespaces and append price
                row_list.append("".join(row.split()))
        #we only append one row data, so use "writerow" instad of "writerows"
        writer.writerow(row_list)
```